# Free software for Mac OS to Execute and test Mathematical formulas?

Tags: osx, math

Recently I have downloaded the trial version Of Wolfram Mathematica on Mac OS. It allowed me to write, test and execute mathematical formulas on specific range of values and view and manipulate results. The problem is that Wolfram Mathematica is too expansive. I can not afford it.

Could you please point out the free, or most affordable application for macOS, that will allow us to test and execute mathematical formulas?

If this is not right place to ask, could you please point out the place, where I can ask this question?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram Alpha web site?

Comment: @EricShain I tried but it seems to be limted to just one line, am i right? I wish to have normal editor to work with.

Comment: Very possibly. Have you looked here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems? You might try SageMath: http://www.sagemath.org. Or possibly: http://maxima.sourceforge.net

Comment: @EricShain I will give try the systems you mentioned. Thank you.